# group update a array in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array $cart result like

```
      array:5 [▼
  188 => array:17 [▼
    "user_id" => ""
    "product_id" => "188"
    "qty" => "2"
    "date" => "03-05-2020"
    "product_type" => "rear type"
    "custom_color_title" => ""
    "custom_color_price" => ""
    "bolt_title" => ""
    "bolt_price" => ""
    "hub_center_rings_title" => ""
    "hub_center_rings_price" => ""
    "wheel_spacers_title" => ""
    "wheel_spacers_price" => ""
    "tire_pressure_title" => ""
    "tire_pressure_price" => ""
    "product_price" => 1890
    "product_size" => ""
  ]
  176 => array:17 [▼
    "user_id" => ""
    "product_id" => "176"
    "qty" => "2"
    "date" => "03-05-2020"
    "product_type" => "wheel type"
    "custom_color_title" => ""
    "custom_color_price" => ""
    "bolt_title" => ""
    "bolt_price" => ""
    "hub_center_rings_title" => ""
    "hub_center_rings_price" => ""
    "wheel_spacers_title" => ""
    "wheel_spacers_price" => ""
    "tire_pressure_title" => ""
    "tire_pressure_price" => ""
    "product_price" => 1680
    "product_size" => ""
  ]
  224 => array:17 [▶]
]
```

how to update user_id value from this array and insert in database?,the index values of array id product value so i confused how update this array.

Comment: do you want to update the `user_id` value with the index of the array? for example: if index is 176 then user_id:"176"?

Comment: @AlwaysSunny no the user id get from sesion value

Comment: so lets say user id from session is 100 then for all the user_id value in the array  will be 100 right?

Comment: @AlwaysSunny yes

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all to write some code? What you're asking seems it can be done by looping through the contents of your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with simple `foreach()` loop to set the `user_id` value from session,

```
foreach($result as $key=>$value){
   $result[$key]['user_id'] = $_SESSION['user_id']; 
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Array ( [188] => Array ( [user_id] => 272 ) [176] => Array ( [user_id] => 272 ) [224] => Array ( [user_id] => 272 ) ) ,the answer only show this not show fullresult

Comment: @andrewghosh try it again

Comment: the old answer is working ,my mistake sry!!! ,i print the wrong variable